Adding Google Account in Android Studio IDE Not Working - Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1
I am getting below error while adding the Google Account in Android Studio I have try the below methods still having same issue

Changing the Browser

Clearing the Cache of both browser and IDE

Removing the Access on Google Account for Android Studio.
Error: User authorization failed (Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.google.gct.login2.settings.GoogleLoginApplicationSettings$Companion.getRefreshTokenKey, parameter user)




hello, same problem here. have you found any solution?

Issue seems to be fixed in Android Studio Meerkat. I myself have not been able to get this to work in Ladybug.
